# Question about unique factorization domains.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my book a theorem states that if we have a UFD, say, $D$ then any finite set of nonzero elements of $D$ also have a greatest common divisor in $D$.

Im struggling with the proof, it starts of by letting $a_1,a_2,....,a_n$ be our finite set of nonzero elements (from $D$), then they say that if one of these elements is a unit then it is "clear that it will act as a greatest common divisor on the set". I dont see how this is "clear", i mean, this statement says that if we have a unit in a UFD then this unit must divide ALL other elements of $D$, is this really true?

Comment: Unit is invertible.

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ A unit is a divisor of $\,1,\,$ and $1$ divides all $\,d\in D,\ $ so, $ $ by transitivity $\ u\mid 1\mid d\,\Rightarrow\,u\mid d.\,$ In words: a factor of a factor remains a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition :

In an Integral Domain $R$ we say $u$ divides $a$ if there exists $b$ such that $a=ub$

Think of  $a=u(u^{-1}a)$...

Comment: I really didnt think of this, thanks.

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: I do not understand the reason why most of your questions are left with answers that are not accepted.... Do you have any other issues with this question?

Comment: I was just about to accept your answer, it said I had to wait another 6 minutes so i grabbed a sandwich, be patient :)

Comment: No No... Question is not about accepting "my" answer... Question is about "Not accepting" answers of other questions... :D